# debian wget cannot fork

Tags: linux, fork, wget

wget not working on my debian server from now:

```
wget http://anydomain.hu/anyimage.png
/usr/local/bin/wget: 3: /usr/local/bin/wget: Cannot fork
```

running "top" command:

```
Tasks:  89 total,   1 running,  88 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,0 us,  0,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 99,0 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   1017080 total,    64316 used,   952764 free,     2264 buffers
KiB Swap:  1675260 total,    42488 used,  1632772 free,    22564 cached
```

i don't know what's the problem pls help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reinstall wget? If not try `apt-get install --reinstall wget`
and try again to download anything.

Comment: Yes i tried reinstall then reboot but still the same...

Comment: What about internet connection? Try to ping google.

Comment: Yes ping ok. Keith Thompson's solution will be good i think.

Comment: @rossifumi: Then why did you accept an answer that didn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `wget` command is normally in `/usr/bin`. Since yours is in `/usr/local/bin`, it appears you've installed a different command with the same name.

And given that the error message appears to include a line number, I'm guessing that your `/usr/local/bin/wget` is a shell script that's intended to be a wrapper around the standard `wget` command.

For example, if you had something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q "$@"
```

because you want to turn off `wget`'s output, then your script will invoke itself recursively. After some number of iterations it will be unable to fork a new process, and it will terminate.

If so, changing the script to invoke `/usr/bin/wget` explicitly should fix it.

Comment: yes i delete wget file in "/usr/local/bin" now with wget command says " -bash: /usr/local/bin/wget: no such file or directory" but with "/usr/bin/wget" command it works

Comment: THANKS PERFECTLY WORKING NOW!